# Two ways of declaring properties in VB - what is the difference?

Tags: c#, vb.net

What is the difference between these two snippets?

```vb
Public Property UserName As String
```

and

```vb
Public Property User As String
    Get
        Return _User
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _User = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I am sorry if this is a duplicate or stupid question. I am not used to VB.NET, I'm more used to C#. I am trying to translate this into C# and I have no room for mistakes.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference. The first is just the short version of the second.

But if you want to restrict the setter or do something more in the properties than to get/set the variable, you need to use the second version.

So it's the same as (in C#)

```
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

[Auto-Implemented Properties (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx)

[Auto-Implemented Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

Comment: I thought this feature is exclusive to C#. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to have a lower visibility setter in a VB auto-property? If not, this feature sounds pretty useless.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: If you need to have different access levels  for the getter/setter, you need to use the second approach. But you can make it   `readonly` in the short version and assign default values in VB.NET (unlike in C#).

Comment: You can make it readonly in the short version? The article you liked sounded like you couldn't. (Private setter is typically a hack for readonly properties)

Answer (score 4):

The first one (an auto-implemented property) will automatically create the backing field for you, so you don't have to declare `_User` yourself, as in your second example.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx):

> When you declare an auto-implemented property, Visual Basic
>   automatically creates a hidden private field called the backing field
>   to contain the property value. The backing field name is the
>   auto-implemented property name preceded by an underscore (_). For
>   example, if you declare an auto-implemented property named ID, the
>   backing field is named _ID.

Comment: The only answer to at least mention `_User`

Answer (score 1):

One of them is shorter :)

In the first case, it's an automatically implemented property that does the same thing as the second case, except you can't see or use the backing field.

The C# equivalent, by the way, is:

```
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just the [VB version of automatically implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx).

So the C# equivalent would be:

```
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Note that VB allows default values for automatically implemented properties, whereas C# doesn't - you'd need to set the property to the default value in the constructor.

Comment: Interesting that the example shows VB auto properties can get default values on the same line whereas they would have to be set in the constructor in C#.

Comment: I wasn't aware there is this equivalent in VB.Net. I thought it's exclusive to C#. Thanks

Comment: I will test _"whereas C# doesn't - you'd need to set the property to the default value in the constructor"_ to confirm